# sqlalchemy orm without sessions, transactions

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to preform insert, update, delete queries without session.add, session.commit just using orm model classes and engine.

Something like:

```
us = User(name='john')
engine.execute(us)
```

Comment: If you don't want to use SQLAlchemy and its features then don't use it. What is the rational to avoid core functionality here?